# What is the between < and cat at a UNIX shell?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm studying linux, and found that the input operator symbol '<' appears to work the same as the command 'cat'.

```
➜  /tmp echo "test" > testfile
➜  /tmp cat testfile 
test
➜  /tmp <testfile 
test
```

I want to know what the difference is between them.

Comment: `<testfile` isn't actually guaranteed to do that; all the POSIX spec requires is that it open `testfile` for input, but not that it read its contents. I assume your shell is `zsh`, perhaps?

Comment: ...in general, if you're trying to figure out how Linux-in-general works experimentally, I might suggest you pick a different shell. `zsh` fixes enough design mistakes in the POSIX sh specification that using it to learn can easily result in habitual bugs when writing code for any other shell.

Comment: ...this isn't in any way specific to Linux, so I changed the title and tagging to be more generic.

Answer (score 2):

#### In the exact usage given

```
cat testfile
```

...is guaranteed to behave as demonstrated in your question if your `cat` command is POSIX-compliant (and not overridden with a shell function, alias, alternate command with the same name earlier in your `PATH`, etc etc).

---

```
<testfile
```

...by contrast, will often (particularly, if your shell is `ash` or `dash` or `ksh` or `bash`) do nothing at all -- opening `testfile` on stdin, and then closing it and going on to the next command.

#### As input source to another command

```
cat testfile | foo
```

...sets up a FIFO, or pipe, between `/usr/bin/cat` and `foo`. Thus, the separate `cat` program needs to read and write each byte of `testfile` before that content can be read by `foo`, and `foo` can read the file only front-to-back, in the order that `cat` writes it.

```
foo <testfile
```

...connects a file handle open to `testfile` directly to the stdin of `foo`. It has a real file descriptor, and so can use `seek()` calls to jump around in the file, reread parts, have different subprocesses process different parts of `testfile`'s content (without needing to do a big front-to-back read in the main process and parcel out components), etc.

Comment: Thank you very much,you are right that my shell is *zsh*.

Comment: Glad to help. Is there anything else I should cover to make this answer complete enough to accept?